# Why isn't the background image populating in XSLT file

Tags: html, css, xml, xslt

I have the following XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template name="displayPano" match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="/root">
            <xsl:variable name="imageSrc" select="imgPano/img/@src" />
            <div class="demo">
                <div id="myPano" class="pano" style="background-image: url('{imageSrc}'); background-size: auto 100%; background-position: 0px 50%; background-repeat: repeat-x;">
                <div class="controls">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="left"></a>
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="right"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <imgPano>
        <img src="/uploadedImages/myfolder/TEST/PANO.jpg" alt="pano image" />
    </imgPano>
</root>
```

ASP.net:

```
<CMS:ContentBlock ID="cbPano" runat="server" DefaultContentID="111111" DisplayXslt="displayPano.xsl" />
```

When I go to the page, I see the following (source):

```
<div id="myPano" class="pano" style="background-image: url(''); background-size: auto 100%; background-position: 0px 50%; background-repeat: repeat-x;"><div class="controls"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="left"></a><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="right"></a></div></div>
```

How can I resolve it so that the background image is displayed correctly.

I need to be able to execute the following Jquery on page load:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#myPano").pano({
                img: "{$imageSrc}"
            });
        });
    </script>
```

How can I add that to the XSL directly.

Comment: You have to get variables with $, try: `... style="background-image: url('{$imageSrc}'); ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from using `$` when referencing variables, I would suggest you write your stylesheet

- without named templates
- without `xsl:for-each`, because looping through a single element does not make sense

But your actual problem might be more complex and there are scenarios where loops and named templates are actually helpful.

Why do you store the image path in a variable anyway? In this specific case, it seems to me that

```
style="background-image: url('{imgPano/img/@src}'); background-size: auto 100%; background-position: 0px 50%; background-repeat: repeat-x;"
```

would also be readable and more straightforward.

**XSLT Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/root">
            <xsl:variable name="imageSrc" select="imgPano/img/@src" />
            <div class="demo">
                <div id="myPano" class="pano" style="background-image: url('{$imageSrc}'); background-size: auto 100%; background-position: 0px 50%; background-repeat: repeat-x;">
                <div class="controls">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="left"></a>
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="right"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**HTML Output**

```
<div class="demo">
   <div id="myPano"
        class="pano"
        style="background-image: url('/uploadedImages/myfolder/TEST/PANO.jpg'); background-size: auto 100%; background-position: 0px 50%; background-repeat: repeat-x;">
      <div class="controls">
         <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="left"/>
         <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="right"/>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I updated my question. Can you please assist. Thanks. I +1 your question. If you feel I need a new question, please let me know.

Comment: @SiKni8 I don't think I understand the edit to your question. Do you really need a `script` element in the output that literally contains `{$imageSrc}`? And now that you updated the question: what is the problem? What does not work? Is it an XSLT, JS or Jquery problem?

Comment: I am trying to using the script for panoramic purposes. The script loads the image to ensure it is used correctly. I realized without the script, even with the background image it won't work :/

Comment: @SiKni8 That does not answer my question I think: _"And now that you updated the question: what is the problem? What does not work? Is it an XSLT, JS or Jquery problem?"_

Comment: Bit of both I think. But as far as my question goes you helped me so I accepted your answer.